# Mocking Http Request Content in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Good afternoon,
I am trying to write some unit tests for web application and I find it difficult
to grasp the concept how I should do it.

```
  var provider = GetMultipartProvider();
  var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

  var bannerFromRequest = result.FormData["Banner"];
```

I read data like this, and I would like to know is there a way to mock data somehow that I could either, send my own data, like creating that multipart form data or by browsing or with selenium.. Any help would be useful

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

use [Moq](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino%20Mocks%20Partial%20Mocks&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

[1](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino%20Mocks%20Partial%20Mocks&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1): https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart or you can try

[Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino%20Mocks%20Partial%20Mocks&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how it will allow me to pass mocked data instead of having to recreate the exact situation. Because that method only happens when something is submitted in website